# Why is this gst-launch script not displaying any video window?

Tags: gstreamer

The following works without a hitch on my machine (notice that I'm basically just doing a full loop back to my autovideosink in one command):

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc is-live=true ! openh264enc ! rtph264pay ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

I get the demo window and see the test source video.

I then try to do the same, but over UDP. So, I have two scripts on the same computer. One acts as the server:

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe videotestsrc is-live=true ! openh264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=3000
```

And the other acts as the client:

```
.\gst-launch-1.0.exe -v udpsrc port=3000 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

The problem is that no video window shows up when I run it over UDP using the server/client method above. All I get (on the client side) is the following output to the console:

*Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.263728000  9200 000002902E7336F0 WARN            d3dvideosink d3dhelpers.c:1146:d3d_set_window_handle: Window HWND already set to: 0
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock*

What about transmitting over UDP is causing things to not work in this example? Thanks so much.

Comment: I assume you are starting the receiver after the sender? In that case you will miss the SPS/PPS data and won't be able to decode the stream and therefore not get any window.

Comment: What happened then ? @Ben

Comment: Sorry for the late response @RC0993. Unfortunately, nothing. I still don't get a visual window. I just tried it. I started the player side first, waited a few seconds, and then started the server side code. Same behavior. 

I'm going to try this in Linux this morning and see if I get a different behavior with the same scripts. I'll report back my findings here.

Comment: Okay, I've confirmed it runs on Linux (well, Bash for Windows). I had to modify the "client" script a tad to include caps="application/x-rtp", but once I did, I am able to get a visual window. I run the client first, and then run the server. I have to conclude something isn't working right on Windows. I will try the same on an Ubuntu install and get back (to make sure this isn't some quirk with running it under Ubuntu for Windows).

Comment: I wasn't able to get a Linux distro up easily at work. But the fact it works fine under Bash for windows is telling (especially since it's the same machine). I might send something to the gstreamer distribution groups too.